Python time module not working on Jupyter Notebook
I am new to Python but this seems very weird to me. I am learning multiprocessing and using Jupyter notebook. Below is my code
from multiprocess import Process
import time
def longSquare(num,results):
    print('Check!')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(num**2)
results={}
time.sleep(1)
print('Check1')
p1=Process(target=longSquare, args=(1,results))
time.sleep(1)
print('Check2')
p2=Process(target=longSquare, args=(2,results))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

when I run this I get an error on the cmd prompt

line 3, in longSquare NameError: name 'time' is not defined. Did you forget to import 'time'?

and the output is -

Check1
Check2

How is it that the time.sleep(1) outside the function works but not the one inside the function?

I get Check1 then NameError: name 'results' is not defined and used multiprocessing (OP typo?).  Also see this blog.  Jupyter has issues with multiprocess(ing).  If on Windows you put the target function in a separate .py file and need to use multiprocessing.Pool to run the function.

yes, sorry, there is a results={} before the first time.sleep(1). fixed the question.

multiprocess isn't multiprocessing.

@Akx well, it isn’t clear that it isn’t a typo. results  was left out. OP should clarify, but it doesn’t change the fact that Jupyter has a problem with multiprocessing in general and it may be the same solution.

I think it's mainly because you are using non-standard package multiprocess (different from standard multiprocessing) with jupyter environments.
If you just started learning multiprocessing, I recommend using standard multiprocessing with standalone scripts to avoid following issues, because it's well documented. There are strange behaviors of multiprocessing in jupyter. Though I didn't fully understand it, I'll try to explain what I currently know. Please correct me in comments if I made a mistake.

The jupyter notebook is known to behave very differently on multiprocessing than standalone scripts. My current understanding is that, jupyter kernel acts like an interactive python interpreter, and you cannot use standard multiprocessing in an interactive shell as stated in official docs, because multiprocessing relies on conditions like __name__ == '__main__' to separate parent and child process (which you didn't do, and it definitely would raise error with multiprocessing, not sure whether multiprocess did some trick to handle this), but __main__ are handled differently in interactive environments. This answer mentioned that the codes are first serialized before they are passed to interactive environments, and official pickle failed to serialize functions.
Luckily, an extension of multiprocessing that uses dill as a serializer can serialize functions, which makes multiprocessing partially usable. One of such implementation is the multiprocess you are using. However, the serializing process lost some information including the globally loaded module, in your case time. So when it's deserialized in the interactive enviroments, it can execute exactly the same bytecodes/instructions, but it cannot access the global value that doesn't yet exist. To make it work, you may need to import everything again in your function, or try to write the function in a different file and import it.
Moreover, you will find your example behave normally in a Linux environment, both in Jupyter and standalone scripts. This is because on Linux the fork system call is used to create a separate process, which copies all the variables (including imported time) into the new process and continue. However, on Windows there is only spawn, which starts a brand new process and start from the beginning, so initially it has nothing.
